# understanding switch in verb tenses

Tags: tenses

In the following paragraph, the main discourse started in present tense(ask), but then switched to past tense (**might**). Why is such a switch allowed?

> Microeconomists and macroeconomists ask different types of questions.
>   A microeconomist **might** be interested in answering such question as:
>   How does a market work? What levels of output does a firm produce?

Comment: Didn't you [already ask this question](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/132895/2303) (or one very much like it) already?

Comment: They are different. That paragraph switched to the future tense. Also, I'm told that the author's writing cannot be trusted.

Comment: "A microeconomist might be interested in answering such question as..." is not past tense.

Comment: @Mr.ShinyandNew安宇 I looked into the dictionary, "might" is the past tense of "may"..

Comment: @user133466 That is one use of the word, yes, but that is not what this sentence is expressing.

Comment: @Mr.ShinyandNew安宇 I'm confused.. please elaborate. I'm not good with verb tenses. why is one use of the word allowed?

Comment: _Might_ is not in the past tense. _Might_ is a [modal auxiliary verb](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/modals.html,) and modal auxiliary verbs have **no** tense.

Comment: @JohnLawler Would the sentence be any different if we replace might with "may"?

Comment: Of course. _May_ is a different modal auxiliary verb; so are _can_ and _could_, which also mean "possible", one way or the other. And they all have different meanings and syntax and logic. This is not a "tense" matter, it's a matter of using the right verb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sentence you've highlighted is not using a past tense. It is using the [conditional mood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_mood#English). It expresses that there exist some microeconomists who would ask questions such as "How does a market work?". Maybe some microeconomists won't ask that question, specifically, but some will.

Wikipedia says this:

> The modal verbs *could, might, should* and *would* may in some contexts be regarded as conditional forms of *can, may, shall* and *will* respectively. What is called the English conditional mood (or just the conditional) is formed periphrastically using the modal verb *would* in combination with the bare infinitive of the main verb. (Occasionally *should* is used in place of would with a first person subject – see *[shall and will](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shall_and_will)*. Also the aforementioned modal verbs *could, might* and *should* may replace *would* in order to express appropriate [modality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linguistic_modality) in addition to conditionality.)

Comment: There are a lot of explanations for this simple use (modality, conditional, auxiliaries etc). It's very overwhelming. What would a layman need to know the rules of modal auxiliary verbs to be relatively proficient at writing essays, letters, short stories? Thank you!

Comment: Calling it "the conditional mood" explains nothing about the usage; it just gives it a name. If you want to say there is a conditional mood in English, why not an optative and a benedictive as well?